# dropdown and textarea element in HTML

Tags: html, css, user-interface

So I just started learning HTML recently, and practicing on creating some simple forms which involves a dropdown menu, followed by an input area such as textbox and textarea.

I just realized that textarea can be used if we were to accommodate line breaks in the input which regular textbox can't in HTML so i have the following form:

[image]

The problem I'm facing now is that if we were to look at the "Report" row, the textarea placement is a little odd in which it caused some unnecessary spacing to the next row input which is ID. Also, the "Report" dropdown seemed to be out of place compared to the other dropdown which is followed by a "textbox".

Is there anything i could do to even out the spacing of the textarea and somehow align the "Report" dropdown to the textarea like the other dropdown could?

My HTML code is as below:

```
<html lang = "en">
<body>
<form>
    <div class = "con1">
        <select id = "dropdown">
            <option>Name</option>
        </select>
        <input type = "text">
    </div>
    <div class = "con2">
        <select id = "dropdown">
            <option>Class</option>
        </select>
        <input type = "text">
    </div>
    <div class = "con3">
        <select id="dropdown">
            <option>Report</option>
        </select>
        <textarea id="id_in"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class = "con4">
        <select id = "dropdown">
            <option>ID</option>
        </select>
        <input type = "text">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Bit confused on the question, but this might be where you need to start involving some CSS

Comment: I strongly recommend making a concerted effort to learn modern CSS and best practices as early as possible. Learning it piecemeal or later will result in terrible HTML structure and reliance on outdated approaches to solving problems in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you use Bootstrap or something like that, it easier to build website with and more simple CSS styling

Answer (score 0):

This is where CSS can be used to align everything the way you want, try setting fixed or % based widths. Also you use the same id="dowpdown" multiple times. Id avoid doing that. If you want to give multiple elements the same identifier i would suggest using a class.